# How do I statically type a response from `window.fetch` with Flow?

Tags: flowtype

I'm `window.fetch`'ing a response from an JSON API, and I'd like to type check my access to the response. For example:

```
type Result = {|+text: string, +metadata: {...}|};

type ApiResponse = Response & {|
  json: () => Result,
  text: null,
|};

const getResult = (): Promise<ApiResponse> => fetch(url);
// access to getResult().then(r => r.json()) is type checked against Result
```

But Flow fails to type check with:

```
Error: src/data/fetcher.js:18
                                             v-
 18: export type ApiResponse = Response & {|
 19:   json: () => Promise<Result>,
 20:
...:
 23: |};
     -^ exact type: object type. Inexact type is incompatible with exact type
987: declare function fetch(input: RequestInfo, init?: RequestOptions): Promise<Response>;
                                                                                ^^^^^^^^ Response. See lib: /private/tmp/flow/flowlib_211b7075/bom.js:987
```

Which I guess makes sense because it can't reconcile `fetch`'s return type of `Promise<Response>` with `getResult`'s return type of `Promise<ApiResponse>`.

**How can I constrain that the thing `getResult` is returning is a Promise?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I constrain that the thing getResult is returning is a Promise?

Type it as a `Promise<Response>`

The type for `Response.json()` [already resolves to `any`](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/2a2c77c61caf0fb0dda48bdf0ccbb53c4b6755f0/lib/bom.js#L986), so you can assert it is whatever type you want:

> ```
> declare class Response {
>    ...
>    json(): Promise<any>;
>    ...
> }
> ```

The next question you might have is "How do I let Flow know the type returned upon calling json()?"

Type that as whatever you're expecting. Something like this:

```
fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((obj: Result) => {
        // Access your obj here
        // (Preferably with some level of checking to make sure
        //  the API returned a valid object)
      })
```